# child menu hidden by contentplaceholder items in asp.net web forms with masterpage

Tags: asp.net

This should not have happened but I have not been able to  figure out what am I doing wrong.
I have created a web form from a masterpage and the menu with header and footer is in the masterpage. 
When I debug the web form after placing controls in the contentplaceholder what I find is that the child menu of the parent menu is hidden by the web form contentplaceholder items.
Any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: It is not clear how you had placed your contentplaceholders in masterpage and controls in web page. Please provide code snippet to illustrate your issue correctly.

Comment: I solved it. thanks for viewing anyway :)